# Flow: Coercing an object-with-nullable-property to object-with-non-nullable-property?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is there a way of expressing two related types - one with a nullable property, one without - in such a way that you can coerce one to the other following a check at runtime?

eg -

```
type Stat = {
  count: ?number,
}
type StatWithCount = {
  count: number
}

let stats: Array<Stat> = [{count: null}, {count: 2}]
let validStats: Array<StatWithCount> = []

for (let i=0; i<stats.length; i++) {
  const stat = stats[i]
  if (stat.count !== null) {
    validStats.push(stat) // This type is incompatible with object type
  }
}
```

https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAysCGwoF4oG8BQUoGMD2ArgHbABcUA-EQQLYBGEATgDQYC+GoksCwA6gEtgACwDChEinRZcEslGr0m7DBgA2EJAGdeW8gEFGjeCAA8cRAD4pAbTT5i86mrVtm6ByXIAmNgF11TSgAN3g1AQATC2A9KENjM2jBEXFHa1QbAIwAMzxGKAAKDSQBZAAGAG4oAVMdRC0AOg0iAHMRKoEAak6ASmlsYqg6pFRhrRsBAOwBbMLhhs8kAEJkVGc1PsxsbFDwqN0GsAItYQLhnpkONiA

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, flow does not support this.

Use type casting at one's own risk:

```
if (stat.count !== null) {
  validStats.push(((stat: Object): StatWithCount))
}
```